# mysqli prepared statement search form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hello for a second time folks.

I asked a question recently about cleaning up some ugly code I had been cooking up and received the help I was asking for very quickly. Thanks for that!

original question thread is here: [PHP - Search database and return results on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845541/php-search-database-and-return-results-on-the-same-page/42845681#42845681)

I was quickly directed to use prepared statements in mysqli instead of what I had been doing to avoid SQL injections and such. I knew this advice would come my way, so it was no surprise. So I did some more digging and have re-written the original code accordingly. But now I have broken the form.

Anyone willing to take a look to see what I am missing? I am new at all of this and my searching on the internets has not helped me to debug this on my own.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Client Search Results</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">      
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">

<fieldset>
<h4>Search For Client</h4>
<input name="search" placeholder="Enter Name Here" type="text">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>

</form>
</div>

<div class='container'>    
<form id='contact' action='edit.php' method='post'>

<fieldset>
<h4>Search Results</h4>
<select size="5" style="width:100%" name='id' >

<?php
// Include database communication info
include("../../comm/com.php");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Search
$search = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT client_id, firstname, lastname, city, state  FROM client WHERE firstname LIKE ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($client_id, $firstname, $lastname, $city, $state); 

if($result > 0) {
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<option value='$client_id'>$firstname $lastname - $city, $state</option>";
  }
}
$stmt->close();
?>

</select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>View Selection</button>
</fieldset>

</form>
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-writing this code many times, and after receiving help from many different direction, this is the code that I settled on. Works like I want and seems to be solid.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Client Search Results</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">      
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">

<fieldset>
<h4>Search For Client</h4>
<input name="search" placeholder="Enter Name Here" type="text" autofocus>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>

</form>
</div>

<div class='container'>    
<form id='contact' action='edit.php' method='post'>

<fieldset>
<h4>Search Results</h4>
<select size="5" style="width:100%" name='client_id' >

<?php

// Retrieve Search Term
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
}

// Include Connection Credentials
include("../../comm/com.php");

//Connection to Database
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Connection Error Check
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    echo "Sorry, there seems to be a connection issue.";
    exit;
}

// Prepared Statement For Database Search
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT client_id, firstname, lastname, city, state FROM client WHERE firstname LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?")) {

// Bind Search Variable
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $search, $search);

// Execute the Statement
    $stmt->execute();

// Bind Variables to Prepared Statement
    $stmt->bind_result($client_id, $firstname, $lastname, $city, $state);

// Fetch Values
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

// Display Results of Search
        echo "<option value='$client_id'>$firstname $lastname - $city, $state</option>";
    }
}

// Close Statment
$stmt->close();

// Disconnect from Database 
mysqli_close($link);
?>

</select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>View Selection</button>
</fieldset>

</form>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```